# error of saving a pdf file without read-only options on win 7

Tags: pdf, windows-7, adobe

I am trying to add some comments to a pdf file that is opened by Adobe Reader XI on win 7.

But, when I saved the pdf file, I got error:

```
The file may be read-only, or another user may have it open. Please save the document with a different name or in a different folder
```

After searching and doing many research, I thought that this can be fixed by closing preview-pane in the windows explorer.

But, I got the same error.

I also tried to save it to a different folder with a different name. I got the same error again.

I have checked the properties of the pdf file, it allows commenting and no read-only option is checked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the processes running in Windows Task Manager? This might happened when there are two or more processes are running for the same Adobe PDF resource. If that so, end them first and open the file again. Then add the comments to the file and save it.

Comment: I opened the only one pdf file. Thanks !